# Merge two spreadsheets in Python with Pandas, by nearest 'Time' in 'Time' Column, values in XX:XX:XX format

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge, timestamp

Writing my first program to organize some data, have been practicing python for several months. This little program will be used in the near future with an RFID reader prototype I am developing. I have successfully taken a .txt and .xls, pulled the relevant info, now I want to match them up based on the timestamp in XX:XX:XX format. The .txt is a readout from my GPS, the .xls contains tag info, from RFID tags.

I only need the GPS location paired with the tag ID's based on the closest timestamp.

Please take a look at what I have so far and lend any direction or advice you may have.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

filename_xls = '11_4_TAG.xls'
df = pd.read_excel(filename_xls)
tag_data=(df[['Time', 'TagID']])
#print(tag_data)

filename = '11_4_GPS.txt'
df_gps = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=r"\s+", skiprows=17, skipfooter=3, engine='python', encoding="unicode_escape")
gps_data=(df_gps[['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Time']])
#print(gps_data)

pd.merge_asof(tag_data, gps_data, on='Time', direction='nearest')
#print(pd.merge_asof)
```

I have tried many variations of "on" and "direction" and "by"

Here are the outputs for my two new data sets:

tag_data

```
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
        Time                     TagID
0   10:18:32  E280116060000207A633DAB6
1   10:18:57  A15427AABB00112233445566
2   10:19:07  E280116060000207A6336C96
3   10:19:09  E280116060000207A6341969
4   10:19:34  E280116060000207A633E5B9
5   10:19:40  E280116060000207A633A846
6   10:19:56  A94439112233445566778899
7   10:20:01  E200001D52120136069068C0
8   10:20:05  E280116060000207A633DA16
9   10:20:07  A63367112233445566778899
10  10:20:12  E280116060000207A633A836
11  10:20:15  E280116060000207A633CBD9
12  10:20:18  E200001D5212006106702126
13  10:20:20  A39223112233445566778899
14  10:20:28  E280116060000207A633DCC6
15  10:20:50  A02257AABB00112233445566
16  10:22:24  E280116060000207A633DA26
17  10:22:44  E280116060000207A6336AC6
18  10:23:43  E280116060000207A633DA46
19  10:24:03  E280116060000207A6336CA6
20  10:24:22  E280116060000207A633DC96
21  10:28:01  C10002AABB00112233445566
22  10:28:05  013193AABB00112233445566
23  10:28:12  017072AABB00112233445566
24  10:28:22  023764AABB00112233445566
25  10:28:42  A15800AABB00112233445566
26  10:28:49  E280116060000207A6336CC6
27  10:28:51  E280116060000207A6344236
28  10:29:00  E280116060000207A6336CB6
29  10:29:01  E280116060000207A633CBB9
30  10:29:08  E280116060000207A6341959
31  10:29:11  A72546AABB00112233445566
32  10:29:15  A93853112233445566778899
33  10:29:15  A93853AABB00112233445566
34  10:30:46  A13832AABB00112233445566
35  10:30:52  A02533AABB00112233445566
36  10:30:58  00111160600002078899CBA9
37  10:31:23  A83503AABB00112206906A73
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

gps_data

```
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
         Latitude      Longitude      Time
0    N43°03.6205'  W085°57.5513'  10:17:46
1    N43°03.6205'  W085°57.5512'  10:17:49
2    N43°03.6203'  W085°57.5514'  10:17:51
3    N43°03.6202'  W085°57.5511'  10:17:54
4    N43°03.6199'  W085°57.5518'  10:17:57
..            ...            ...       ...
342  N43°03.6162'  W085°57.5477'  10:33:03
343  N43°03.6163'  W085°57.5472'  10:33:06
344  N43°03.6168'  W085°57.5477'  10:33:09
345  N43°03.6167'  W085°57.5477'  10:33:11
346  N43°03.6163'  W085°57.5486'  10:33:14

[347 rows x 3 columns]
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Error Code:

```
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Software\Python Programs\Data_parse\data_parse_xls.py", line 15, in <module>
    pd.merge_asof(tag_data, gps_data, on='Time', direction='nearest')
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 563, in merge_asof
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1483, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 884, in _get_join_info
    (left_indexer, right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1789, in _get_join_indexers
    return func(left_values, right_values, self.allow_exact_matches, tolerance)
  File "pandas\_libs\join.pyx", line 966, in pandas._libs.join.__pyx_fused_cpdef
TypeError: No matching signature found
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to merge on Time? because those time have to exactly match to be merged

Comment: It's currently the only two data points I have in common between the two spreadsheets. I'm capturing GPS data while also capturing tag data, the prototype I am developing will capture the GPS info at the time of Tag read. I guess I won't need this software anymore at that point. Reading 'Pandas' they talk about finding the nearest integer, I believe it can be datetime, timestamp or intiger. I can not get it to work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MhDG7 said, you can only merge on values that match exactly. So your first task is for each timestamp in gps_data find the closest match among timestamps in tag_data. The key line in the below is this one

```
tag_secs_for_gps_secs = [min(tag_data['Secs'], key = lambda tag_secs: abs(tag_secs - gps_secs))  for gps_secs in gps_data['Secs'] ]
```

that does exactly that. Here, for each gps time expressed in seconds (see below) we find an element among tag_data timestamps (also expressed in seconds) that minimizes the absolute distance between the two

Here is the full script
First we create toy data

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime

gps_data_raw = StringIO(
    """
Latitude,Longitude,Time
N43°03.6162',W085°57.5477',10:33:03
N43°03.6163',W085°57.5472',10:33:06
N43°03.6168',W085°57.5477',10:33:09
N43°03.6167',W085°57.5477',10:33:11
N43°03.6163',W085°57.5486',10:33:14
    """)
gps_data = pd.read_csv(gps_data_raw)

tag_data_raw = StringIO(
    """
Time,TagID
10:33:01,C10002AABB00112233445566
10:33:05,013193AABB00112233445566
10:33:12,017072AABB00112233445566
10:33:22,023764AABB00112233445566
10:33:42,A15800AABB00112233445566
10:33:49,E280116060000207A6336CC6
10:33:51,E280116060000207A6344236
    """)
tag_data = pd.read_csv(tag_data_raw)
```

Then we convert timestamp to datetime object and eventually to (integer) seconds from the base_date

```
base_date = datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
gps_data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(gps_data['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
tag_data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(tag_data['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
gps_data['Secs'] = gps_data['Time'].apply(lambda t: int((t-base_date).total_seconds()))
tag_data['Secs'] = tag_data['Time'].apply(lambda t: int((t-base_date).total_seconds()))
```

Then we match timestamps, stick them into the dataframe, and merge on that column

```
tag_secs_for_gps_secs = [min(tag_data['Secs'], key = lambda tag_secs: abs(tag_secs - gps_secs))  for gps_secs in gps_data['Secs'] ]

gps_data['Nearest_tag_secs'] = tag_secs_for_gps_secs
merged_data = gps_data.merge(tag_data, left_on = 'Nearest_tag_secs', right_on = 'Secs')
```

The resultimg dataframe `merged_data` can use a bit of cleanup but reproduced here in full so you can see what happened

```
|    | Latitude     | Longitude     | Time_x              |   Secs_x |   Nearest_tag_secs | Time_y              | TagID                    |   Secs_y |
|---:|:-------------|:--------------|:--------------------|---------:|-------------------:|:--------------------|:-------------------------|---------:|
|  0 | N43°03.6162' | W085°57.5477' | 1900-01-01 10:33:03 |    37983 |              37981 | 1900-01-01 10:33:01 | C10002AABB00112233445566 |    37981 |
|  1 | N43°03.6163' | W085°57.5472' | 1900-01-01 10:33:06 |    37986 |              37985 | 1900-01-01 10:33:05 | 013193AABB00112233445566 |    37985 |
|  2 | N43°03.6168' | W085°57.5477' | 1900-01-01 10:33:09 |    37989 |              37992 | 1900-01-01 10:33:12 | 017072AABB00112233445566 |    37992 |
|  3 | N43°03.6167' | W085°57.5477' | 1900-01-01 10:33:11 |    37991 |              37992 | 1900-01-01 10:33:12 | 017072AABB00112233445566 |    37992 |
|  4 | N43°03.6163' | W085°57.5486' | 1900-01-01 10:33:14 |    37994 |              37992 | 1900-01-01 10:33:12 | 017072AABB00112233445566 |    37992 |
```

Comment: This is great thank you. I will dive into this today and play around. I get what you are both saying now about merging on the same value. The readings take place over several minutes as I walked around my lot of Campers and read tag data. I will need to match on minutes also, but I can definitely see a path to making that happen now. I never realized how creative you had to be to write code, really enjoying it. Thank you both.

Comment: no problem. To be clear my code matches on the **total** seconds since the base date (so a unique number for any timestamp) not just the last two digits of your timestamp

Comment: Oh awesome, I tried, unsuccessfully to convert the 'timestamp' to some sort of intiger, glad to see I was on the right track last night. I will update with progress later.

Comment: Thank you this worked great! I will be studying/googling parts of this code for a few days to fully understand, but I get the birds-eye view of what's going on. I copied and pasted a small subset of my original data to get it right first, now I will work on getting my two spreadsheets to populate in the StringIO, in the way you have pictured.

Comment: @Beasmazter, `SrtingIO` stuff there is to have a standalone example only that is not dependent on any files, and you do not really need that part in your final solution. Yours `df = pd.read_excel(filename_xls)` should work fine (well, you may want to watch out for whitespace around your values, but other than that there should be no issues).

Comment: holy crap, it works just like that, love it! I ended up switching around tag_data and gps_data in the timestamp matching section so it wouldn't duplicate TagID's to match up every GPS reading. lining up perfectly, huge thanks!